# API gateway websocket IAM authorizer

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I configured my `$connect` websocket route's auth to `AWS_IAM` however, I can still establish a connection without even signing the url with credentials. I expect that handshake should fail if url is not signed with valid credentials but it seems that the IAM authorizer is not being called/invoked. I tried signing the url with invalid credentials but it would just connect successfully.

Are there any other configurations that are needed?

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of trying to make the IAM authorizer work for my websocket api, I have finally figured out the problem. I tried to manually create a custom lambda authorizer and applied to the `$connect` route and deployed the api. As expected, the custom authorizer worked. I changed it back to `AWS_IAM` authorizer and again, I manually deployed the api in the console and it finally worked. I think the reason is that since I have to configure the `$connect` route's authorizer via `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route` resource like this:

```
// serverless@2.16.0
resources: {
  Resources: {
    SconnectWebsocketsRoute: {
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route',
      Properties: {
        AuthorizationType: 'AWS_IAM'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

every time I perform `serverless deploy -s stage --force`, it somehow doesn't see this as a new changes in configuration thus it skips updating this in Cloudformation. I'm not 100% sure about this though so any other thoughts are welcome.